# chrome vs chromium [extension comparisions]

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I'm trying to find some interesting data when comparing the extension, add-on, lists of the open-source browsers Firefox and Chromium.
What I'm interested in is the multi-homing extensions (extensions that are available on both the browser lists).
But when browsing on the Chromium extension list I found out that it was the same list as the one from Chrome.
**Questions:**
-Can I use every extension on Chrome also on Chromium?
-If not, where can I find a list on what extensions I can use on Chromium?.

Comment: [AskUbuntu addressed your question properly.][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/a/6257/9480

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the Chrome and Chromium codebases are basically identical (besides some ancillary functionality like auto-updates). Chrome is just a branded version of Chromium, so all the same extensions will work in both.

Answer (score 0):

I investigated on this subject and found 2 articles on the subject.

### [What Is The Difference Between Google Chrome And Chromium Browser?](http://What%20Is%20The%20Difference%20Between%20Google%20Chrome%20And%20Chromium%20Browser?)

And more recent

### [What’s the Difference Between Chromium and Chrome?](http://What%E2%80%99s%20the%20Difference%20Between%20Chromium%20and%20Chrome?)

I have strong bias toward Chromium as a developer, using it as basis for testing tools, and browser tests.
Also have substantial untruest in Googles interests.

The second article above claims that Chromium is devoid from Google backdoor data collection (spyware). This claim was **not** backed with tests. Further recent testing and verification is required.